# Table header displays small

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have got a little table with a header and after I have added some more rows with inputs to the table, the header has started not to take the whole width of the table.Any suggestions?Would be really grateful.

**HTML**

```
<table id = "table">
<th id = "header">HEADER</th>
<tr id = "row">
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
</tr>
<tr id = "row">
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
</tr>
<tr id = "row">
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
    <td><input type = "text" id = "det_0_0"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
#table{
width:30%;
height:200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:50px;
border:2px inset rgb(0,0,0);
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#header{
height:25px;
max-height:25px;
text-align:center;
font-size:16px;
width:100%;
font-family:Georgia, serif;
background-color:rgb(30,114,41);
color:rgb(245,245,250);
border-bottom:2px inset rgb(0,0,0);
}
#row{
font-size:14px;
font-family:Georgia, serif;
word-wrap:break-word;
background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<th id = "header" colspan="3">HEADER</th>
```